# Obtaining Excel worksheet reference by worksheet name via C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm currently obtaining a handle to a Excel worksheet by using the below C# code:

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(15);
//Get the worksheet "SubSignOff" number
```

Is there any way that I can obtain the same by using the worksheet name `"SubSignOff"` ?

Comment: Might have stumbled upon the answer ... (am still in the process of verifying it)

 worksheet.GetType().InvokeMember(subEntityName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, Sheets, oArgs2);

Answer (score 45):

Instead of the using [`Excel.Workbook.Sheets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.sheets(VS.80).aspx) collection, it's easier to access the [`Excel.Workbook.Worksheets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.worksheets(VS.80).aspx) collection, that way you can utilize early binding.

In your case, it could look something like the following:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;

Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyWorkbook.xls",
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

// The key line:
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets["SubSignOff"];
```

Hope this helps...