# Check excel sheet for specific header

Tags: c#, ssis, import-from-excel

I need to check Excel files for a sheet containing a specific header in C#.

The sheet names, order and quantity are variable. I need to check all the sheets for the one containing a specific header and then store the name in a variable for later processing.

I can currently get all the sheet names but I am not able to check if it contains what I am looking for or not.

The goal is to get the sheet name and insert it in a SQL statement to process the file in a SSIS package.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
public void Main()
    {            
        string excelFile;
        string connectionString;
        OleDbConnection excelConnection;
        DataTable tablesInFile;
        string[] excelTables = new string[5];
        excelFile = Dts.Variables["User::var_MonitoringFile"].Value.ToString();
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source= "+ excelFile +
             ";Extended Properties=\"EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES; IMEX=1;\"";
        excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        excelConnection.Open();
        tablesInFile = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");
        DataRow tableInFile = tablesInFile.Rows[0];
        Dts.Variables["User::var_ExcelSheet"].Value = tableInFile["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

        excelConnection.Close();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: how are you accessing excel to get the sheet names? Office interop? Jet DB providers? Gembox?

Comment: show your code so that we can see how you are instantiating the instance of the InterOp object.. also check this link for previous asked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491100/obtaining-excel-worksheet-reference-by-worksheet-name-via-c-sharp

Comment: I have looked at interop, but this is on a server and they don't want us to install Office interop on it.