# C# Excel how to work with already opened workbook

Tags: c#, excel

This is a question that was taken from the learning's of my last question: [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264589/how-to-copy-data-from-c-sharp-winform-and-paste-into-excel-worksheet)

I need to be able to send text to a selected worksheet that is already opened.

This, I think is close but it didn't work:

```
        string wb = cmb_BookName.Text.ToString();
        string ws = cmb_SheetName.Text.ToString();

        if (chkContainer.Checked)
        {
            Excel.Application oexcel = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook wkbk = (Excel.Workbook)oexcel.Workbooks[wb];
            Excel.Worksheet wksk = (Excel.Worksheet)wkbk.Sheets[ws];
            Range cellRange = wksk.Range["D48:D48"];
            cellRange.Value = cboContainer.Text;
        }
```

The code builds without errors but when running it stops at the line trying to get the workbook, see image.[image]

So basically my question still is how do I work with an excel workbook that is already opened?

Seems like most of the articles that I find are opening an excel file and then working with it. In my case, I need to work with an already opened excel workbook.

Answer (score 0):

There are some helpful answers (some of them, not the accepted answer) to this question here: [Accessing an open Excel Workbook in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682678/accessing-an-open-excel-workbook-in-c-sharp)

But here is my summarized answer.

Try this:

**First**
You must access the currently running application (if there are multiple instances of Excel running already, this might not work everytime)

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// I use a global application object
Application excelApp;

// Gets the first running instance of the Excel.Application
// If that fails, the error is caught, and a new application is created
try
{
   excelApp = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
}
catch (COMException ex)
{
   excelApp = new Application
   {
      Visible = true
   };
}
```

**Second**
Get the desired workbook by path, (must be windows style, i.e. "C:\Desktop\myWorkbook.xlsx")

```
Workbook myWorkbook = null;

foreach (Workbook xlWorkbook in excelApp.Workbooks)
{
   if (xlWorkbook.FullName == "<path to workbook>")
   {
      myWorkbook = xlWorkbook;
   }
}
```